# Case insensitive pandas dataframe.merge

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am struggling with the easiest way to do a case insensitive merge in pandas. Is there a way to do it right on the merge? Do I need to use (?i) or a regex with ignorecase? In my code snippet below I am joining some Countries where it may be "United States" in one file and "UNITED STATES" in another and I just want to take the case out of the equation. Thank you!

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys

env_path = sys.argv[1]
map_path = sys.argv[2]


df_address = pd.read_csv(env_path + "\\address.csv")
df_CountryMapping = pd.read_csv(map_path + "\CountryMapping.csv")

df_merged = df_address.merge(df_CountryMapping, left_on="Country", right_on="NAME", how="left")

....
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Lowercase the values in the two columns that will be used to merge, and then merge on the lowercased columns

```
df_address['country_lower'] = df_address['Country'].str.lower()
df_CountryMapping['name_lower'] = df_CountryMapping['NAME'].str.lower()
df_merged = df_address.merge(df_CountryMapping, left_on="country_lower", right_on="name_lower", how="left")
```

Comment: Thanks! Works exactly as I need!

Answer (score 43):

```py
df_merged = pd.merge(df_address, df_CountryMapping, left_on=df_address["Country"].str.lower(), right_on=df_CountryMapping["NAME"].str.lower(), how="left")
```

Comment: It's a good practice to add also some explanations to the code example.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this doesn't have an explanation, since it is the best answer. This method does not modify the original dataframes, it only applies the lowercase for the inputs to the merge method. Very well done.

Comment: How to apply the `lower` method on multiple columns like `left_on=df1['col1','col2'].str.lower()`?

Comment: @AbuShoeb You can use applymap to lower both columns `df1[['col1','col2']].applymap(lambda x: str(x).lower())`

Comment: This is the correct answer. It only lower cases the columns when performing the merge and retains the original column values.

Comment: Hmm when I try the .applymap method of @RohanPawar to join on multiple columns I receive a KeyError message, however it then lists the column values.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest lowering the column names after reading them

```
df_address.columns=[c.lower() for c in df_address.columns]
df_CountryMapping.columns=[c.lower() for c in df_CountryMapping.columns]
```

Then update the values

```
df_address['country']=df_address['country'].str.lower()
df_CountryMapping['name']=df_CountryMapping['name'].str.lower()
```

And only then, do the merging

```
df_merged = df_address.merge(df_CountryMapping, left_on="country", right_on="name", how="left")
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to convert the column names of both data frames to be all lowercase. So something like this:

```
df_address = pd.read_csv(env_path + "\\address.csv")
df_CountryMapping = pd.read_csv(map_path + "\CountryMapping.csv")

df_address.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower(), inplace=True)
df_CountryMapping.rename(columns=lambda x: x.lower(), inplace=True)

df_merged = df_address.merge(df_CountryMapping, left_on="country", right_on="name", how="left")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with ".str.casefold()" for a more comprehensive incorporation of ASCII and different language characters. If your just using English alpha chars it should be the same as ".str.lower()"

```
df_address['country_casefolded'] = df_address['Country'].str.casefold()
df_CountryMapping['name_casefolded'] = df_CountryMapping['NAME'].str.casefold()
df_merged = df_address.merge(df_CountryMapping, left_on="country_casefolded", right_on="name_casefolded", how="left")
```