# merge method compared with SQL query

Tags: pandas

I used the inner merge method of pandas data frame on the data that was derived from MySQL. I expected the count to match with the inner join SQL query. Does merge method work exactly like inner join SQL query?

```
farmer_ucd=pd.read_sql('select * from usercredential_dtl  ', con=farmer_engine)
farmer_upe=pd.read_sql('select * from userprofile_dtl  ', con=farmer_engine)

farmer_upe.merge(farmer_ucd, how='inner', on=['user_id'])

99979 rows × 51 columns
```

The count of SQL query is higher than merge method of pandas.

```
select count(*) from usercredential_dtl as  ucd inner join userprofile_dtl as upe
on ucd.User_Id = upe.User_Id 

count(*)
109254
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Case insensitive pandas dataframe.merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761915/case-insensitive-pandas-dataframe-merge)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because pandas compares column case as well and mysql will perform case -insensitive search.

```
farmer_upe['user_id']=farmer_upe['user_id'].str.lower()
```

When I changed the common column to lower case, it matched with the mysql query count.