# Pandas: match string in df1['a'] with df2 ['a] and assign correspoding value df2['b'] to df1['new']

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

### Background

I am looking at the **Coronavirus dataset** from CSSEGISandData (github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git). I am trying to create a **plotly choropleth map** that shows the **number of cases for each US county**.

Here is an example of the csv dataset from CSSEGISandData. I have **concatenated multiple days** into one file:

```
         Province/State Country/Region         Last Update  Confirmed  \
259               Chicago             US 2020-01-24 17:00:00        1.0   
3028           Orange, CA             US 2020-02-01 19:53:00        1.0   
2445       San Benito, CA             US 2020-02-03 03:53:02        2.0   
3181      San Antonio, TX             US 2020-02-13 18:53:02        1.0   
4762  Humboldt County, CA             US 2020-02-21 05:13:09        1.0   

      Deaths  Recovered  Latitude  Longitude            file  \
259      0.0        0.0       NaN        NaN  01-24-2020.csv   
3028     0.0        0.0       NaN        NaN  02-01-2020.csv   
2445     0.0        0.0       NaN        NaN  02-24-2020.csv   
3181     0.0        0.0   29.4241   -98.4936  03-04-2020.csv   
4762     0.0        0.0       NaN        NaN  02-27-2020.csv
```

### Problem

I want to modify this plotly example ( https://plot.ly/python/mapbox-county-choropleth/ ) and use the counties from my dataframe, to do this i first need to:

1. Match all counties in my file, to fips codes.

I found a list of fips codes here (https://github.com/kjhealy/fips-codes) :

```
   fips            name state
0     0   UNITED STATES   NaN
1  1000         ALABAMA   NaN
2  1001  Autauga County    AL
3  1003  Baldwin County    AL
4  1005  Barbour County    AL
```

How do I create a new column in my pandas dataframe, with the right fips code?

Here is my code importing the COVID data and the fips codes

```py
!git clone https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19.git

#@title Import and Option to show print more data 
import pandas as pd 
import glob


#Get the coronavirus data for the US 
path = r'/content/COVID-19/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports' # use your path
all_files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv") #collect all files in one
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
df = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False) #one dataframe
filter_USA=frame['Country/Region']=='US'
USA= frame[filter_USA]
print (USA.head())


#Get the county data for the US with fips 
county_url= 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kjhealy/fips-codes/master/state_and_county_fips_master.csv'
county = pd.read_csv(county_url)
print ( county.head())
```

Now I need to match the USA Province/State names with the county names, and assign the the fips value.

```py
#somethin like 
for all USA['Province/State'] match to county.name
USA['fips'] = county match fips value
```

### EDIT

Putting in a longer version fo the dataframe to show the different problems with the names:

- upper and lower case problem
- some are city names not counties
- some have added writing to them

```
3027                                Los Angeles, CA
2369                                Santa Clara, CA
2003                                 San Benito, CA
2310                                    Madison, WI
2470                                    Seattle, WA
6175                                    Chicago, IL
2237                           San Diego County, CA
2805                           San Diego County, CA
1765                                San Antonio, TX
3657                            Humboldt County, CA
737                                 Santa Clara, CA
3629                           San Diego County, CA
2468                          Sacramento County, CA
1543                                    Ashland, NE
1549                                     Travis, CA
1560                                   Lackland, TX
420            Lackland, TX (From Diamond Princess)
410              Travis, CA (From Diamond Princess)
404               Omaha, NE (From Diamond Princess)
6436              Omaha, NE (From Diamond Princess)
4289           Lackland, TX (From Diamond Princess)
5047             Travis, CA (From Diamond Princess)
2421    Unassigned Location (From Diamond Princess)
1769                                      Tempe, AZ
303     Unassigned Location (From Diamond Princess)
4981    Unassigned Location (From Diamond Princess)
5015                          Sacramento County, CA
4208    Unassigned Location (From Diamond Princess)
```

Comment: Merge the data frames, filtering the added one to include only the columns you want (i.e. `fips`).

Comment: the issue is that the names might not match 100%, the upper case and that one includes the state. but i can try

Comment: also, they arent the same lenght

Comment: You can split and filter the portions you need.

Comment: How much variation is there between the names of the counties in your dataframe vs. those in the FIPS data? Is it only an issue of capitalization? Or are there abbreviations here and there, or other problems with matching these keys up?

Comment: It seems like you could read in the FIPS data as a new dataframe and do a left join on it with your present dataframe. Maybe there are some case sensitivity parameters to the operation to take advantage of. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29762212/7915759

Comment: @Todd I've added a longer version of the dataframe, Some names have longer descriptions tied to them, as well as the upper and lowe case problems.

Comment: Ill look into the left join

Comment: @David8, can you please tell me which file I could pull from the COVID-19 git that has relevant US data? One that serves as a good example of the problems with matching. I'll see if I can experiment with it.

Comment: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/03-09-2020.csv  this file has some examples, however if you use my code it will pull all of them and put all the US data into one dataframe, so you can see all the example s

Comment: I recommend using the NYTimes [GitHub](https://github.com/nytimes/covid-19-data) data for US Country plots. I have already done something similar on [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/jacobkrucinski/coronavirus-covid-19-data-extrapolation)